# Corrupt /var/lib/dpkg/arch file, can't use apt or boot

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, dpkg, plymouth

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64-bit.

I booted into Ubuntu just now, and suddenly, for seemingly no reason, it hung on the Plymouth boot screen, on 'Hold until boot process finishes up'. The boot process never finished up.

So, I looked around for solutions, and, after booting into root bash in recovery mode, I tried one. The solution involved reinstalling/removing `plymouth`, so I tried using apt to do that. But I got a locale error, which I fixed by regenerating locale.

Then, when using apt to attempt to remove plymouth, I got this error:

```
dpkg: error: fgets gave an empty string from 'var/lib/dpkg/arch'
```

Turns out dpkg is a bit broken.

Looking through `/var/lib/dpkg/`, most files seem intact and uncorrupted.
`available`, `diversions`, `statoverride` and `status` are all readable, largish files. The `arch` file however, is corrupt (only 11 bytes, and `cat` produces `MmSt`.)

My question is, how can I regenerate this `arch` file and fix my computer?

Even it involves reinstalling dpkg...

I'm extremely grateful for *any* help (please)!

Update: creating a new `arch` file with `amd64` as the contents fixes the above error. The new error is:

```
dpkg: error: too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
```

`cat` for that file produces some binary gobbledygook, maybe it's corrupt too?

Update: the solution I settled on was a fresh install of Ubuntu. Too many files were corrupt :(

Comment: What do `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` say?

Comment: `amd64` for the first one, the second one gives the error listed above.

Comment: What does `file /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` say? it should be ASCII text afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post this as an answer, but my solution was a fresh install of Ubuntu. Sorry to disappoint anyone here looking for a real fix, but in my case it turned out that somehow, a whole swathe of system files had become irreversibly corrupted, and a reinstall was the only viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch
amd64
i386
```

(ended by newline each)
This is on a 18.04.1 bionic multiarch setup. 
So usually you use only one of them depending on your system.

The other file is a list of locations and the packages which created them (I suppose)

```
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File 
/etc/dbus-1/system.d dbus/noawait
/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d dbus/noawait
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services dbus/noawait
/usr/lib/mime/packages mime-support/noawait
/usr/share/applications mime-support/noawait
/etc/rsyslog.d rsyslog/noawait
/usr/share/mime/packages shared-mime-info/noawait
/usr/share/info install-info/noawait
/usr/share/icons/hicolor hicolor-icon-theme/noawait
/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/share/fonts fontconfig/noawait
/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts fontconfig/noawait
/usr/share/texmf/fonts fontconfig/noawait
/usr/share/icons/gnome gnome-icon-theme/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules libgtk-3-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules libgtk-3-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0:amd64/noawait
/etc/sgml sgml-base
/usr/share/sgml sgml-base
/usr/share/xml sgml-base
/usr/share/texmf tex-common/noawait
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist tex-common/noawait
/var/lib/dictionaries-common/hunspell dictionaries-common
/etc/ufw/applications.d ufw/noawait
/etc/init ureadahead/noawait
/etc/init.d ureadahead/noawait
/usr/share/doc-base doc-base/noawait
/usr/share/doc/rarian-compat doc-base/noawait
/usr/share/gconf/defaults gconf2
/usr/share/gconf/mandatory gconf2
/usr/share/gconf/schemas gconf2
/usr/share/GConf/gsettings gconf2
/usr/share/menu menu/noawait
/usr/lib/menu menu/noawait
/etc/menu-methods menu/noawait
/usr/share/app-info/icons appstream/noawait
/usr/share/app-info/yaml appstream/noawait
/usr/share/app-info/xml appstream/noawait
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions libreoffice-common/noawait
/usr/lib/libreoffice libreoffice-common/noawait
/usr/share/slib guile-2.0-libs:amd64/noawait
/etc/lsb-release plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text/noawait
/usr/man man-db/noawait
/usr/share/man man-db/noawait
/usr/local/man man-db/noawait
/usr/local/share/man man-db/noawait
/usr/X11R6/man man-db/noawait
/opt/man man-db/noawait
/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list ntp/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:amd64/noawait
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:amd64
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:i386
/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules libgtk-3-0:i386/noawait
/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules libgtk-3-0:i386/noawait
/lib/udev/hwdb.d udev/noawait
/usr/lib/systemd/catalog systemd/noawait
/etc/init.d systemd/noawait
/usr/share/package-data-downloads update-notifier-common
/usr/share/applications desktop-file-utils/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins libvlc-bin:amd64/noawait
/usr/share/cups/ppd-updaters cups/noawait
```